# Secondary monitor not detected by debian, but visible in NVidia-settings utility

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, video, output

## The problem

I did a fresh install of Debian 11 (`Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux`) on my Omen 15 (`15-en0xxx`) laptop.

SecureBoot is currently **disabled** in my UEFI settings to ensure my issue is not related to unsigned software issues.

My laptop configuration is as follows:

```
KERNEL : 5.10.0-21-amd64

CPU : AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 3.000GHz

GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile

ENVIRONMENT : GNOME 3.38.6
```

I successfully installed the `nvidia-driver` package. In the next section my output logs should confirm this.

The problem is that when I plug in my second monitor, Debian **does not detect this monitor at all** and nothing is displayed on this monitor. This issue is present on both the HDMI port of my laptop and when using the Thunderbolt-to-DVI adapter I used to use when I had windows installed.

The `nvidia-settings` utility **does** detect the monitor correctly (both over HDMI and DVI-Adapter - see photo) but still nothing is displayed on the monitor and it is not visible in debian settings.

[image: Monitor is visible in nvidia-settings]

The monitor and cable are confirmed working both by plugging in to another laptop **and** the GRUB bootloader cursor is displayed during the GRUB "phase" on the laptop with the issue. Once linux boots the monitor seems to lose connection and is no longer usable from within the linux installation.

## Setup and environment information

**All commands and output provided below were ran with the external monitor connected to the laptop.**

Output for `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.00  
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1440x900     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00  
   1024x768     144.00  
   800x600      144.00  
   640x480      144.00
```

---

Output for `xrandr --listproviders`

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x54 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:Unknown AMD Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:06:00.0
Provider 1: id: 0x1f7 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

---

Output for `xrandr --listmonitors`

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP 1920/344x1080/194+0+0  eDP
```

---

Output for `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia 
  v: 470.161.03 
  Device-2: AMD Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera type: USB 
  driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.40.0 5.10.0-21-amd64 LLVM 11.0.1) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.3.5
```

---

Output for `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:102 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

---

Output for `lsmod | grep nvidia`

```
nvidia_drm             73728  2
nvidia_modeset       1204224  4 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35516416  107 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        278528  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   626688  13 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,amdgpu,nvidia_drm,ttm
```

---

## What I have tried

I have ran the `nvidia-xconfig` utility and rebooted. This generated an `xorg.conf` and my external monitor worked as expected. The built-in monitor of my laptop did however no longer present output (simply a black screen with a single static cursor in the top-left corner). This is not a solution to my problem.

Removing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and rebooting resulted in the built-in monitor of my laptop working again, but now the external monitor is again not working and not detected by debian settings (but, as before, visible in `nvidia-settings`).

## What I would like to achieve

Being able to use my external monitor and main monitor of my laptop. The external monitor should extend my desktop and be manageable in the debian display settings.

If anyone could help me get this setup to work properly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Additional command output can be provided if any information is missing in my question.

Comment: Not an OS issue. As it happens in most hybrid graphics laptops the external monitor can only be used with the dGPU (Nvidia), not with the iGPU (AMD) that you're currently running with. You should use Nvidia X Server settings, select the High-Performance (Nvidia) profile, apply, reboot and test.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I do have Nvidia X Server Settings installed (=nvidia-settings) however I do not have any option related to, or equivalent to "select the High-Performance (Nvidia) profile". After some searching I found you most likely are referring to the "PRIME Profiles" tab of nvidia-settings, but this tab is simply not present on my installation (see image in question). Could you elaborate on how I can achieve what you stated?

Comment: Indeed that's what I was referring to. There are CLI tools, prime-select or something, but I'm not sure if they're available for Debian (I use Ubuntu and Debian based Deepin where such option has always been available in the Nvidia tool, at least for Intel+Nvidia; I understand AMD+Nvidia can be a different and more challenging "beast"). You may want to try this https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/official-driver-384-59-with-geforce-1050m-doesnt-work-on-opensuse-tumbleweed-kde/52620/2

Comment: A part of that thread alongside with information I gathered through my (admittedly way too long) troubleshooting process lead me to fix the issue. Thanks for the link. I will now catch some sleep and type a well formulated solution to this question tomorrow.